# Automatically apply default endpoint conventions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to apply `RequireHost` and some other conventions on all the non-API endpoints like Swagger, GraphQL Playground, Hangfire Dashboard etc. The simplest and straightforward solution is doing it manually in the `UseEndpoints` configuration action. For example

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(builder =>
{
    // API
    builder.MapGraphQL();
    builder.MapControllers();

    // API Docs
    builder.MapSwagger().RequireHost("*:5656");
    builder.MapSwaggerUI().RequireHost("*:5656");
    builder.MapGraphQLPlayground().RequireHost("*:5656");
});
```

I'd want to make the separation more clear and automatic. What I have in mind is `UseDocEndpoints` extension method that will apply all the required conventions by default.

```cs
// API
app.UseEndpoints(builder =>
{
    builder.MapGraphQL();
    builder.MapControllers();
});

// API Docs - RequireHost("*:5656") should be applied automatically
app.UseDocEndpoints(builder =>
{
    builder.MapSwagger();
    builder.MapSwaggerUI();
    builder.MapGraphQLPlayground();
});
```

I'm not sure it's doable, but I believe the custom implementation of the `IEndpointRouteBuilder`, `IEndpointConventionBuilder`, and `EndpointDataSource` should be involved. Unfortunatly I couldn't find any helpful documentation of these types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [RouteGroupBuilder](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/1b8d57c658a05429d5f26699d8bf0dedaedb2ee0/src/Http/Routing/src/RouteGroupBuilder.cs) I was able to implement the following

The `UseDocEndpoints` extension method:

```cs
public static IApplicationBuilder UseDocEndpoints(
    this IApplicationBuilder app,
    Action<IEndpointRouteBuilder> configure)
{
    app.UseEndpoints(routeBuilder =>
    {
        var builder = new DocumentationEndpointBuilder(routeBuilder);
        configure(builder);
    });

    return app;
}
```

The `DocumentationEndpointBuilder`. It implements both `IEndpointRouteBuilder` and `IEndpointConventionBuilder`, so you can both `Map*` and configure per endpoint conventions:

```cs
public class DocumentationEndpointBuilder
    : IEndpointRouteBuilder, IEndpointConventionBuilder
{
    private readonly IEndpointRouteBuilder _outerEndpointRouteBuilder;

    private readonly List<EndpointDataSource> _dataSources = new();
    private readonly List<Action<EndpointBuilder>> _conventions = new();
    private readonly List<Action<EndpointBuilder>> _finallyConventions = new();

    public DocumentationEndpointBuilder(IEndpointRouteBuilder outerEndpointRouteBuilder)
    {
        _outerEndpointRouteBuilder = outerEndpointRouteBuilder;
        _outerEndpointRouteBuilder.DataSources.Add(new DocumentationEndpointDataSource(this));
        ((IEndpointConventionBuilder)this).ApplyDocumentationConventions();
    }

    ICollection<EndpointDataSource> IEndpointRouteBuilder.DataSources =>
        _dataSources;

    IServiceProvider IEndpointRouteBuilder.ServiceProvider =>
        _outerEndpointRouteBuilder.ServiceProvider;

    IApplicationBuilder IEndpointRouteBuilder.CreateApplicationBuilder() =>
        _outerEndpointRouteBuilder.CreateApplicationBuilder();

    void IEndpointConventionBuilder.Add(Action<EndpointBuilder> convention) =>
        _conventions.Add(convention);

    void IEndpointConventionBuilder.Finally(Action<EndpointBuilder> finalConvention) =>
        _finallyConventions.Add(finalConvention);

    private sealed class DocumentationEndpointDataSource : EndpointDataSource, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly DocumentationEndpointBuilder _docsEndpointBuilder;
        private CompositeEndpointDataSource _compositeDataSource;

        public DocumentationEndpointDataSource(DocumentationEndpointBuilder docsEndpointBuilder)
        {
            _docsEndpointBuilder = docsEndpointBuilder;
        }

        public override IReadOnlyList<Endpoint> Endpoints => GetGroupedEndpointsWithNullablePrefix();

        public override IChangeToken GetChangeToken() => _docsEndpointBuilder._dataSources.Count switch
        {
            0 => NullChangeToken.Singleton,
            1 => _docsEndpointBuilder._dataSources[0].GetChangeToken(),
            _ => GetCompositeChangeToken(),
        };

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _compositeDataSource?.Dispose();

            foreach (var dataSource in _docsEndpointBuilder._dataSources)
            {
                (dataSource as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private IReadOnlyList<Endpoint> GetGroupedEndpointsWithNullablePrefix()
        {
            var context = new RouteGroupContext
            {
                Prefix = null!,
                Conventions = _docsEndpointBuilder._conventions,
                FinallyConventions = _docsEndpointBuilder._finallyConventions,
                ApplicationServices = _docsEndpointBuilder._outerEndpointRouteBuilder.ServiceProvider
            };

            return _docsEndpointBuilder._dataSources.Count switch
            {
                0 => Array.Empty<Endpoint>(),
                1 => _docsEndpointBuilder._dataSources[0].GetGroupedEndpoints(context),
                _ => SelectEndpointsFromAllDataSources(context),
            };
        }

        private IReadOnlyList<Endpoint> SelectEndpointsFromAllDataSources(RouteGroupContext context)
        {
            var groupedEndpoints = new List<Endpoint>();

            foreach (var dataSource in _docsEndpointBuilder._dataSources)
            {
                groupedEndpoints.AddRange(dataSource.GetGroupedEndpoints(context));
            }

            return groupedEndpoints;
        }

        private IChangeToken GetCompositeChangeToken()
        {
            // We are not guarding against concurrent RouteGroupBuilder._dataSources mutation.
            // This is only to avoid double initialization of _compositeDataSource if GetChangeToken() is called concurrently.
            lock (_docsEndpointBuilder._dataSources)
            {
                _compositeDataSource ??= new CompositeEndpointDataSource(_docsEndpointBuilder._dataSources);
            }

            return _compositeDataSource.GetChangeToken();
        }
    }
}
```

The `ApplyDocumentationConventions` extension method. The common conventions can be applied here:

```cs
public static TBuilder ApplyDocumentationConventions<TBuilder>(this TBuilder builder)
    where TBuilder : IEndpointConventionBuilder
{
    return builder.RequireHost("*:5656");
}
```